# Choice of canonical generator of cohomology group of $\mathbb{CP}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I'm always having trouble understanding the orientation we consider for a given homology or cohomology group when it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Take specifically the case the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ of $\mathbb{CP}^n$. Here the $-1$ denotes its first Chern class is negative of the generator of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathbb{Z})$. But how do we first choose the orientation of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathbb{Z})$?

One possible approach that I tried to understand this is the following: Consider the case especially for $\mathbb{CP}^1$. We first choose orientation of $H_2(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})$, which is a choice of fundamental class $[\mathbb{CP}^1]$, this is determined naturally by its complex structure. Then by the isomorphism of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_2(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})$, we therefore have a canonical orientation for $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})$, i.e. we define the canonical generator $[\omega]$ to be the one that $<[\mathbb{CP}^1],[\omega]>=1$.

The above argument works fine for $\mathbb{CP}^1$. For $\mathbb{CP}^n$, I'm thinking we should choose the canonical generator of $H_2(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathbb{Z})$ to be the pushforward of the fundamental class of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ to $\mathbb{CP}^n$ under the natural embedding
$$[z_0,z_1] \rightarrow [z_0,z_1,0,...,0]$$

Is this the right way to think about in this setting?

Comment: I do not understand the question: Integer cohomology groups are abelian groups. What do you even mean by an orientation on an abelian group and why would you want to have one? Orientation makes sense for finite-dimensional real vector spaces and, more generally, manifolds and vector bundles.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, editted the problem. I'm talking about the choice of canonical generator of a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What algebraic topology books did you read? If you did not read any, my suggestion is that you do. For instance, Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" is freely available and is, currently, a standard AT textbook. Pretty much any textbook in AT will tell you that the $CP^k\subset CP^n$ has a canonical orientation and its fundamental class $[CP^k]$ defines a generator of $H_k(CP^n)$. Now, dualize to get to the integer cohomology group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the comment! I never actually learned AT systematically. I will take a good look at the book.